# Unable to parse XML file with python.Want to remove a line from python file for it .Help me to remove the line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xml-parsing

hello I am using etree for the parsing the xml file.I am having a problem parsing a xml file.Below are details.

```
<niktoscan .................................... >#don't want to remove this line
<scandetails>
data 
</scandetials>
<niktoscan ....................................> #line 1 to remove
<scandetails>
data
</scandetials>
 <niktoscan ....................................> #line 2 to remove
<scandetails>
data
</scandetials>
</niktoscan>
```

As you can see in above code niktoscan is coming again without closing tag.What i want is to remove the niktoscans lines between the start and end leaving only first niktoscan tag.
I am confuse how to remove the niktoscan lines. Help me on this ploblem with python.

Comment: Sorry i did'nt get you can demonstrate it wit code ??

Comment: It seems your input is not well-formed xml (some close tags are missing). What errors does `etree.parse(input_file)` produce? xml is not line-oriented (though some xml parser can preserve whitespace). Do you want to remove `niktoscan` elements and their children recursively or just the `niktoscan` elements themselves?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i want to remove second and third nicktoscan tag not their childrens, that will serve my purpose..... Thnx hopin for good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to parse your file:

```
with open('niktoscan.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

foundone = False
print type(content)

cleanedContent = []
for line in content:
    print line

    foundnik = line.find('<niktoscan')
    if not (foundnik != -1 and foundone):
        cleanedContent.append(line)

    if foundnik != -1:
        foundone = True
print "\n\n ########### cleaned content ########### \n\n"

for line in cleanedContent:
    print line
```

Then you can put the results through your parser.